# JavaScript table understanding

Tags: javascript

Im trying to figure out what this piece of codes does. i do understand the overall concept, using localStorage to build a table via the DOM methods. I am not quite sure were the table gets the data from? How does the buildtable() know that it is building it self from the Employee data? The understanding is for school hhomework :)

```
if(localStorage.getItem("Employee") == null) {
    var employeeList = [];
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Simon", "Male", "HR", 1999, "SM1@cbs.dk"));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Mads", "Male","IT", 1999,  "MS@cbs.dk"));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Jessica", "Female", "Sales",1998, "JT@cbs.dk"));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Benjamin", "Male","IT", 1997, "BN@cbs.dk"));

    var employeeListString = JSON.stringify(employeeList);
    localStorage.setItem("Employee", employeeListString);
    document.querySelector("#employees").appendChild(buildTable(employeeList));
} else {
    var employeeList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Employee"));
}

//Function creates table for employeeList
function buildTable(data) {
    // creates variable "table"
    let table = document.createElement("table");

        // Create table head and body
        table.appendChild(document.createElement("thead"));
        table.appendChild(document.createElement("tbody"));

        let fields = Object.keys(data[0]);
        let headRow = document.createElement("tr");
        fields.forEach(function (field) {
            let headCell = document.createElement("th");
            headCell.textContent = field;
            headRow.appendChild(headCell);
        });
        table.querySelector("thead").appendChild(headRow);
        data.forEach(function (object) {
            let row = document.createElement("tr");
            fields.forEach(function (field) {
                let cell = document.createElement("td");
                cell.textContent = object[field];
                if (typeof object[field] == "number") {
                    cell.style.textAlign = "left";
                }
                row.appendChild(cell);
            });
            table.querySelector("tbody").appendChild(row);
        });
        return table;

    }

document.querySelector("#employees").appendChild(buildTable(employeeList));
```

Comment: The very last thing in your code is `buildTable(employeeList)`. That's where the data is passed in.

Answer (score 2):

`buildTable(data)` gets its data from the `data` param, which is fed by this line:

`buildTable(employeeList)`

So the table gets its data from the `employeeList` array.

The table column headers are populated from the property names of the objects that make up the array. Since these are the same for each object in the array (i.e. every employee has the same data structure), it's necessary only to read the first one, `[0]`.

So if `data` looks like this:

```
[
    {
        foo: 'bar',
        bar: 'foo'
    },
    {
        foo: 'bar2',
        bar: 'foo2'
    }
]
```

...we can use the first (or any) object to generate the column headings.

Comment: What about the let fields = Object.keys(data[0]);?